# Transferring files via https

Tags: c#, https, file-transfer

We have a 15+MB zip file that we need to transfer over HTTPS.

Currently we are transferring the files one at a time unzipped and uncompressed they are around 94+MB.

So zipping them up makes some sense in saving time.

However, I've been "told" that HTTPS will first unzip the file, to check for any risks I guess, before transferring the file.

Is this actually correct and if so what speed ramifications might this have?

Are there better ways to transfer a 15+MB file rather than HTTPS?

The primary question here is whether HTTPS will unzip the file first.

Comment: "I've been "told" that HTTPS will first unzip the file, to check for any risks I guess" --- don't listen to the person who told that ever

Comment: Yeah I was dubious on that claim and have found no evidence on that on Google but thought I should ask the question none the less.

Comment: It will also listen to your mp3 files if there's any bad words in it

Comment: @C.Evenhuis, Really?  Best not send any of my podcasts then!  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTPS is a secure layer over HTTP. HTTPS does not check content, it only secures the http-part, so that nobody can see the http-data. So, the answer on your question is no: HTTPS will not unzip the file first.